# read matrix data using readdlm in julia

Tags: julia

I was trying to construct graph of [cora citation network](http://networkrepository.com/cora.php) using julia.
The data structure is like below,

```
1 9 1
1 436 1
1 545 1
4 198 1
4 464 1
4 602 1
...
```

the edge is constructed from the node id of first row to the node id of second row. and the third row is indicate the weight of the edge. in this dataset, all edges has weight of 1. cora has 2708 nodes, 5429 edges.

and i wrote julia code like below,

```
function MatrixMarketRead(filename)
     A = readdlm(filename)
     A = A[4:end,1:3]
    return sparse( round(Int64,A[:,1]), round(Int64,A[:,2]), convert(Array{Float64},A[:,3]))
end

dir  = "dataset/"
ln = "cora.mtx"
A = MatrixMarketRead(string(dir,strip(ln)));

print(size(A))
```

and the out put was

> (2708,2706)

this shoould be shape of (2708, 2708) but the result was like this. I'm not sure why this happened. how should i fix this?

Comment: Maybe consider LightGraphs.jl instead (probably together with MetaGraphs.jl).

Comment: But the code should be right. Have you tried something like `maximum(A[:, 2])` to see whether all values are really present? If not, you `sparse` cannot magically infer the matrix to be quadratic. But then you can use the five argument constructor.

Comment: @phipsgabler thanks for your advises. judging from the output, this dataset mostlikely doesn't have all node ids in  its row or column. but what do you mean by five arugument constructor?

Comment: `sparse(A[:, 1], A[:, 2], A[:, 3], 2708, 2708)`.

Comment: Alternatively, allocate `spzeros(2708, 2708)` and mutate it line by line while reading. This would eliminate creating `A` at all.

Comment: @phipsgabler i got the MethodError with that five arugument constructur. im using julia version of 0.5.2 just for your information. do you think its causing this problem?

Comment: Oh pretty sure, yeah. That's _really_ ancient.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As phipsgabler noted in the comments, updating to a newer version of Julia would be step one to resolve this. See here https://julialang.org/downloads/ for details on getting started with the latest version.